# AzureDevOps Release pipeline reports "task commands are not supported for Deployment flow"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a release pipeline in Azure DevOps. This is triggered when a pipeline has created new artifacts. In the stage there is a "Deployment group job" under which a "Copy files to" task hangs.

The release pipeline does everything it is supposed to do, the files are in the right folder on the server afterwards. However, the stage is shown as failed because of `##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)`. These are all debug messages that are displayed and reported as errors. Here is the exact log:

```
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1358664Z ##[section]Starting: Download artifact - Projectname - drop
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1755887Z ==============================================================================
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1756763Z Task         : Download build artifacts
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1757178Z Description  : Download files that were saved as artifacts of a completed build
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1757476Z Version      : 0.225.0
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1758981Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1759368Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts
2023-08-02T13:28:06.1759545Z ==============================================================================
2023-08-02T13:28:07.2631663Z Downloading artifacts for build: 237
2023-08-02T13:28:07.4422738Z Downloading items from container resource #/23506446/drop
2023-08-02T13:28:07.4423852Z Downloading artifact drop from: https://dev.azure.com/.../
2023-08-02T13:28:07.6366162Z Downloading drop/.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs
2023-08-02T13:28:07.6396732Z Downloaded drop/.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs
2023-08-02T13:28:07.6894947Z Downloading drop/Projectname.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache
2023-08-02T13:28:07.6906112Z Downloaded drop/Projectname.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.AssemblyReference.cache
2023-08-02T13:28:07.7254307Z Downloading drop/Projectname.csproj.CopyComplete to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.CopyComplete
2023-08-02T13:28:07.7256054Z Downloaded drop/Projectname.csproj.CopyComplete to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.CopyComplete
2023-08-02T13:28:07.7756486Z Downloading drop/Projectname.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
2023-08-02T13:28:07.7757232Z Downloaded drop/Projectname.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
2023-08-02T13:28:07.8271402Z Downloading drop/Projectname.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
2023-08-02T13:28:07.8276444Z Downloaded drop/Projectname.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
2023-08-02T13:28:07.8598538Z Downloading drop/Projectname.csproj.SuggestedBindingRedirects.cache to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.SuggestedBindingRedirects.cache
2023-08-02T13:28:07.8600738Z Downloaded drop/Projectname.csproj.SuggestedBindingRedirects.cache to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.csproj.SuggestedBindingRedirects.cache
2023-08-02T13:28:07.9045162Z Downloading drop/Projectname.exe to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.exe
2023-08-02T13:28:07.9063783Z Downloaded drop/Projectname.exe to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.exe
2023-08-02T13:28:07.9532621Z Downloading drop/Projectname.pdb to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.pdb
2023-08-02T13:28:07.9553638Z Downloaded drop/Projectname.pdb to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\drop\Projectname.pdb
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4564990Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4575932Z ##vso[task.debug]Nothing more to process, exiting worker 2.
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4576733Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4577320Z ##vso[task.debug]Nothing more to process, exiting worker 3.
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4578355Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4578774Z ##vso[task.debug]Nothing more to process, exiting worker 4.
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4579343Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4579715Z ##vso[task.debug]Nothing more to process, exiting worker 5.
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4580261Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4580671Z ##vso[task.debug]Nothing more to process, exiting worker 6.
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4581244Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4581654Z ##vso[task.debug]Nothing more to process, exiting worker 7.
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4582436Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4582851Z ##vso[task.debug]Nothing more to process, exiting worker 8.
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4583079Z Total Files: 8, Processed: 8, Skipped: 0, Failed: 0, Download time: 1.013 secs, Download size: 23920Bytes
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4583662Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4584039Z ##vso[task.debug]SYSTEM.HOSTTYPE=deployment
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4584575Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4584967Z ##vso[task.debug]RELEASE.DEFINITIONNAME=New release pipeline
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4585586Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4586038Z ##vso[task.debug]RELEASE.RELEASEID=15
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4587045Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4587693Z ##vso[task.debug]RELEASE.RELEASEWEBURL=https://dev.azure.com/.../
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4588350Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4588769Z ##vso[task.debug]TASK.DISPLAYNAME=Download artifact - Projectname - drop
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4589352Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4589757Z ##vso[task.debug]SYSTEM.JOBID=996faecc-c082-4a1c-89b7-231c0e4d67d4
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4590316Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4590717Z ##vso[task.debug]AGENT.VERSION=3.220.5
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4591225Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4591602Z ##vso[task.debug]AGENT.OS=Windows_NT
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4592269Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4593444Z ##vso[task.debug]AGENT.NAME=SERVERNAME
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4766683Z Successfully downloaded artifacts to C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\Projectname\
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4767420Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4768533Z ##vso[task.debug]task result: Succeeded
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4769409Z ##[error]task commands are not supported for Deployment flow. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4769852Z ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]
2023-08-02T13:28:08.4794033Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - Projectname - drop
```

What can I do to either disable these debug messages or to stop them from being evaluated as errors?